# Arabic characters not showing while creating PDF in Windows Phone (WinRT)

Tags: pdf, encoding, windows-runtime, arabic, componentone

I am creating a PDF using componentOne library to create a PDF in my universal application, this is creating a PDF fine for English, but when I create a PDF in Arabic it starts giving garbage characters instead of Arabic characters.

This looks like an encoding issue to me. Please let me know how do we solve such issues generally for creating PDF, even if you do not know about componentOne library. I might pick the clue.

**EDIT:**
Download Stripped down code:

http://1drv.ms/1ABAuqi

Code:

```
async void CreatePdfDocument()
{
    try
    {
        var pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.Letter);
        pdf.Landscape = false;

        // measure and show some text 
        var text = App.GetResource("DocumentHeading");
        var font = new Font("Segoe UI Light", 36, PdfFontStyle.Bold);

        var fmt = new StringFormat();
        fmt.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        // measure it
        var sz = pdf.MeasureString(text, font, 72 * 3, fmt);
        var rc = new Rect(0, 0, pdf.PageRectangle.Width, sz.Height);
        rc = PdfUtils.Offset(rc, 0, 0);

        // draw the text
        pdf.DrawString(text, font, Colors.Orange, rc, fmt);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

[image: What printed in document in case of Arabic]

Comment: Please give an example of your code and output.

Comment: edited the question.. please check